# Check to see if a variable doesn't have Bitwise & X?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have been using a bitwise comparison to check if entities and maptiles have flags in a roguelike game, but I've run into a problem - I need to check in an if() if a tile/ent doesn't have a flag, but I can't figure out how to do it without using an empty if() {} and else { condition; }, an example being:

```
if(Tile->Flags & TILE_INVIEW) {} else { attron(A_DIM); }
```

or

```
if(Tile->Flags & TILE_RENDER) {} else { SetTileFlags(GetTileFlags() + TILE_RENDER); }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reverse your condition:

```
if(!(Tile->Flags & TILE_INVIEW)) {
    attron(A_DIM);
}
```

There is a *not* operator :)

Comment: Thanks.  I thought it might be the ! operator, I just didn't use it correctly.